# SharePoint workflow sending email even if it has been cancelled

Tags: workflow, nintex

I have a SharePoint Workflow which is triggering email in its first stage.
The issue I am facing is that although the workflow has already been cancelled it's still sending the notification email.

- "Workflow email recipient is assigned" to `Created By`
- "Send individually addressed notifications" is checked

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you send a due date mail in your workflow, there is timer job will do it. So, although you have cancelled the workflow , but the timer job is working continue. So, I suggest you after canceled the workflow, please stop the **Notifications** timer job and “**Expiration Policy**” timer job , then restart them.

You’d better remove your workflow after cancelled . Then deploy your workflow again. Then the mail will not still send.

Comment: Or else you can modify the expiration policy. any way redeploying the WF is the best way